# Bind operation at React

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

The handleClickExample method works the way I want  when I use React 's parameterless function with the arrow function the results.
Example :

```
class App extends Component {

 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log("constructor", this)
  }

   handleClickExample = () =>{
    console.log( "handleClickExample Method", this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={this.handleClickExample}>TIKLA</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Result : When I click the button:

**handleClick `Method App {props: {…}, context: {…}, refs: {…}, updater: {…}, handleClickExample: ƒ, …}`**

This is a result I want. However, if I change the same code to a parameterized function, the method does not work when I click the button.

Example:

```
class App extends Component {

 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log("constrcutor", this)
  }

   handleClickExample = (name) =>{
    console.log(name ,"handleClick Method", this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={this.handleClickExample("DOES NOT WORK")}>TIKLA</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Result : When I click the button:

The method does not work. I can solve this problem. If I call the method using the arrow function, the problem is solved.

```
<button onClick={ () => this.handleClickExample("DOES NOT WORK")} ></button>
Or
<button onClick={this.handleClickExample('DOES NOT WORK').bind(this)}>TIKLA</button>
```

What is the difference between parameterized function and parameterless function? Why I also had to use the arrow function when using the parameter function. Or why did I have to bind?
Or Why don't I need to do this in a parameterless function?
He doesn't say I didn't get into the method and find this. I can't call the method.When I click the button, no function works or throws an error.

Or It also works when you do so.

```
handleClickExample = (name) => (e) => {
     console.log(name ,"handleClick Method", this);
}
```

Why did we have to pass the **(e)** parameter here?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the first method for it. You just need to modify your handleClickExample function something as follow:

```
handleClickExample = (name) => (e) => {
     console.log(name ,"handleClick Method", this);
}
```

This is known as currying.

Comment: That's how it works. But why did I have to pass the (e) parameter? What I want to understand is the working logic of the javascript.

Comment: 1) this.handleClickExample means you are creating reference to that function to avoid creating a brand new callback instance on every render and by default bind to its parent.

Comment: I didn't understand what you said. Why are we also passing the (e) parameter? I may not have been able to understand because my Javascript info is not enough. Sorry

Comment: e basically an event object which is being passed to this.handleClickExample

Answer (score 1):

q is function

```
var q = this.handleClickExample // q()
```

q is return result of function

```
var q = this.handleClickExample() // cannot call
```

q is function

```
var q = () => this.handleClickExample() // q()
```

q is function that accepts argument

```
var q = (someArg) => this.handleClickExample() // q('1')
```

q is function that accepts argument and returns function

```
var q = (someArg) => () => this.handleClickExample() // q('1')()
```

q is function that accepts argument and returns function that also accepts argument

```
var q = (someArg) => (otherArg) => this.handleClickExample() // q('1')('two')
```

Your code:

```
var q = handleClickExample = (name) => (e) => {} // q('myName')(e)
// q returns function that returns function
// name is your custom argument
// e is ClickEvent argument, that onClick is passing to callback
```

onClick event requires function, that optionally accepts event argument

Comment: It was very revealing. Thank you :)